# Are these Snort rules redundant?

Tags: networking, security, snort

I was looking through the community.rules made available on the [Snort web page](https://www.snort.org/downloads/#rule-downloads), and noticed these two rules:

```
Rule @ line 2643: alert udp $HOME_NET any -> any 53 (msg:"BLACKLIST DNS request for known malware domain documents.myPicture.info"; flow:to_server; byte_test:1,!&,0xF8,2; content:"|09|documents|09|myPicture|04|info|00|"; fast_pattern:only; metadata:impact_flag red, policy balanced-ips drop, policy security-ips drop, ruleset community, service dns; reference:url,fireeye.com/blog/technical/2013/08/survival-of-the-fittest-new-york-times-attackers-evolve-quickly.html; classtype:trojan-activity; sid:27625; rev:2;)  

Rule @ line 2644: alert udp $HOME_NET any -> any 53 (msg:"BLACKLIST DNS request for known malware domain ftp.documents.myPicture.info"; flow:to_server; byte_test:1,!&,0xF8,2; content:"|03|ftp|09|documents|09|myPicture|04|info|00|"; fast_pattern:only; metadata:impact_flag red, policy balanced-ips drop, policy security-ips drop, ruleset community, service dns; reference:url,fireeye.com/blog/technical/2013/08/survival-of-the-fittest-new-york-times-attackers-evolve-quickly.html; classtype:trojan-activity; sid:27626; rev:2;)
```

Doesn't the `content` option in the first rule (`|09|documents|09|myPicture|04|info|00|`) make the 2nd rule redundant? That is,  the 1st rule will always trigger if the 2nd rule does because its `content` option is a substring of the 2nd's `content` option (`|03|ftp|09|documents|09|myPicture|04|info|00|`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These rules were confirmed to be redundant by the Snort mailing list in [this exchange](http://marc.info/?l=snort-sigs&m=143507194315044&w=2).

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: See the Snort rules email list archive: http://marc.info/?l=snort-sigs&m=143507194315044&w=2